# How to set loss for train_op using tf estimator API when the loss is input-dependent and implemented via a custom loss layer?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tf.keras

I am implementing a CNN model with `tf.estimator` API.

Briefly, the cost/loss function is input-dependent and contains variables to be updated during training. I implemented a custom layer with identical mapping just for calling `add_loss()` and holding the trainable variables for the loss.

However, when I tried to specify `train_op` for `EstimatorSpec` (using `AdamOptimizer`), I have no idea how to retrieve the loss and feed it to `optimizer.minimize()`.

The problem occurred to me when I was trying to implement the Multi-Max-Gaussian-Likelihood loss proposed in [Kendall_CVPR2018](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Kendall_Multi-Task_Learning_Using_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf). 
I adopted the general approach as the example code provided by the paper author on [Github](https://github.com/yaringal/multi-task-learning-example/blob/master/multi-task-learning-example.ipynb), which is defining a custom layer for the loss.

Unfortunately, the aforementioned code uses `Keras`, while I am trying to test it with `tensorflow`, more specifically, `tf.estimator`. In Keras, when calling model.compile(), we can feed `None` as the `loss` argument. But I suppose we cannot pass `None` to the optimizer in tensorflow.

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    ...
    xs = ts.reshape(xs, shape=[-1, ...])
    nn_params = dict(...)
    ys_out = cnn_blabla(x, mode, ** nn_params)
    ...

    loss=???

    ...
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimmizer(params['LEARNING_RATE'])
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
    ...
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(...)


def cnn_blabla(x, mode, n_outputs, ...):
    with tf.variable_scope("blabla", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        layer_out_1 = conv(x, ..., activation=..., name=...)
        layer_out_2 = conv(layer_out_1, ..., activation=..., name=...)
        ...
        layer_out_v = conv(layer_out_u, ..., activation=..., name=...)
        out = CustomLossLayer(n_outputs=n_outputs, name="loss_blabla")(layer_out_v)
    return out


def conv(...):
    ...
```

I expect to train the model with the custom loss, via `tf.estimator` in tensorflow.